# Can I place a long time operation in Service class when I use AlarmManager?

Tags: android

I use AlarmManager to handle a schedule task, the function DoSomething() maybe spend a long time, can I place the function in Service class? Thanks!

In my mind, the Service class can't run a long time operation , it will cause an app to lose response.

```
  @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    initView();
}


   @Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
    pendingIntent = null;
    switch (v.getId()) {

    case R.id.btnService:
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(),
                0,
                new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActionService.class),
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

    alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, now, 5000,
            pendingIntent);
}
}




    public class ActionService extends Service {
    private static int index = 0;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
        super.onStart(intent, startId);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service " + index++ + "Ok1",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         DoSomething();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

   }
```

Comment: it will cause an app to lose response. What do you mean by this?.

Comment: from documentation: `A Service is an application component representing either an application's desire to perform a longer-running operation while not interacting with the user or to supply functionality for other applications to use.`

so you can run long operation at server. you also can use `BroadcastReceiver` to notify about operation completion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use IntentService. Invoke your DoSomething method in onHandleIntent() method from IntentService. It handles performing long-running tasks in background thread so you would not lose responsibility of UI. You just have to remember that IntentService performs one task at a time. It queues incoming Intents and invoke them sequentially. If you want to do it another way try to use Handler and HandlerThread inside classic Service.

Service itself works on UI/main thread - this is why your application become unresponsive.

Comment: @HelloCW Of course you can. IntentService is just a Service subclass.

Comment: @HelloCW Please let me know if my answear helped you.

Comment: Thanks! From the doument  
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html . Service class do can run a long time operation, but why does somebody say Service class can't run a long time operation ?

Comment: @HelloCW Classic Service can perform long running operations, but only when you are handling threads by yourself. By default all Service methods are invoked on UI Thread.

Comment: Thanks, I replace ActionService.class with IntentService , but  It don't  work well when I use PendingIntent.getService(...)

Comment: And more,  it seems that IntentService run only one time even if I set alarmManager.setRepeating(...) and Toast.makeText(...) keep display with the same content.

Comment: @HelloCW You shouldn't override onStart method in IntentService. Override onStartCommand instead. `onStartCommand` is invoked for every incomig startService Intent. `onCreate` is method when you can initialize your service - it's invoked once when service is starting.

Comment: Thanks!   I place my work in  "protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {...}", I don't  override both onStart and onStartCommand

Comment: Sorry, your solution  don't work. The IntentService run only one time even if I set alarmManager.setRepeating(...) and Toast.makeText(...) keep display with the same content.

Comment: @HelloCW - Because you need to put Toast.makeText(...) call in onStartCommand method, not in onStart. Have you tried that ? It would be very helpful if you would paste your current code here.

Comment: From the docment http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html#onStartCommand%28android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int%29, you should not override onStartCommand method for your IntentService. Instead, override onHandleIntent(Intent), which the system calls when the IntentService receives a start request.

Comment: So I place my all works include Toast.makeText(...)  in "protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {...}", but the IntentService run only one time even if I set alarmManager.setRepeating(...) and Toast.makeText(...) keep display with the same content.

Comment: @HelloCW - Ok. Is your counter variable still static. Can you paste entire IntentService code here or maybe in Gist or Pastebin ? Then I will be able to help you better.

Comment: Thanks! I found problem. Toast.makeText(...)  can't be placed in  IntentService because it's not UI thread. so it's Ok after I remove Toast.makeText(...)  from  "protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {...}"

Comment: @HelloCW - That's right ! I completely forgot ! I'm glad that your code is working now. Greetings.